# how to : specify colors for multiple axes chart?

Tags: colors, highcharts, lines, axes

My chart shows up well but the two lines are of the same color. How do I specify different colors for the two lines? Here is my code (fragment) so far:

```
config.pointIndex = null;
  config.areaPoints = new Array();
  config.areaPoints[0] = pointsopens;
  config.areaPoints[1] = pointsclicks;
  var plotLinesopen = createPlotlines(pointsopens);
  var plotLinesclick = createPlotlines(pointsclicks);
  var options = {
     chart : { renderTo : 'areaChart' },
     colors: [
        '#4572A7',
        '#AA4643'
        ],
     xAxis: {
        plotLines1: plotLinesopen,
        plotLines2: plotLinesclick
     },
     series : [ data.pointsopens, data.pointsclicks ]
  };
  if (length > 100) {
     options.plotOptions = {
        area : {
           lineWidth: 1,
           marker : { radius : 1 }

        }
     };
  }
  options = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartDefault, options);
  charts.area = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Thank you.

PS, my code is now:

```
 config.pointIndex = null;
        config.areaPoints = new Array();
        config.areaPoints[0] = pointsopens;
        config.areaPoints[1] = pointsclicks;
        var plotLinesopen = createPlotlines(pointsopens, '#AAAAAA');
        var plotLinesclick = createPlotlines(pointsclicks, '#DDDDDD');

        var options = {
            chart : { renderTo : 'areaChart' },
            xAxis: {
                plotLines: [plotLinesopen, plotLinesclick]
            },
            series : [ data.pointsopens, data.pointsclicks ]
        };
        if (length > 100) {
            options.plotOptions = {
                area : {
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    marker : { radius : 1 }

                }
            };
        }
        options = jQuery.extend(true, {}, areaChartDefault, options);
        charts.area = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

but it still gives me two  dark blue plotlines.  The createPlotlines function looks like so:

```
function createPlotlines(points, colour) {
    // Create plotlines from point data
    colour = typeof colour !== 'undefined' ? colour : '#CCCCCC';
    alert ('colour=='+colour);
    var plotLines = [];
    var middleYval = 0;
    for (var i in points) {
        middleYval = Math.max(middleYval, points[i].y);
        if (points[i].l) { // l property is true if label should be on for this point
            plotLines.push({
                color: colour,
                id: 'plotline'+i,
                value: points[i].x,
                width: 1,

            });
        }
    }
    return plotLines;
}
```

Comment: What's `pointsopens` and `pointsclicks` ?

Comment: collections of points to be plotted - one for an open event another for a click event.  the points get plotted correctly, bit I can't seem to change the color of the plot lines.  they two lines also have differently colored areas underneath.

Comment: This is not possible as of yet. I was also looking to change x-axis lines color. But it doesnt work. Works only if you specify value for single line ==> xAxis.plotLines: {color: '', value: 'VALUE OF LINE ON AXIS'}

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean different colors for the xAxis and yAxis? I only see that this would make one of each. You can definitely set the colors of the axis lines independently.
See this: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/linecolor/), [ref](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--lineColor)

EDIT:
For plotLines you can use [this](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#yAxis-plotLines):
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/plotlines-color/)

Comment: I meant the plotlines, one for the pointsopens and one for pointsclicks.

Comment: sorry, my terminology was all wrong, the color of the lines for a series is what i want to color - the lines connecting all the data points on the chart.  I am using an area chart so I can specify the color under the lines but what about the lines themselves, right now all lines are colored blue.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look the [reference](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart) you'll see that there's no attr named `colors`.
Other problem is that there's no attr `plotLines1` and `plotLines2` as you can see [here](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis-plotLines)

**Solution**: If you want to change a plot line color your have to pass your plotlines thrue an array, like the following and set theire color:

```
var options = {
    chart : { renderTo : 'areaChart' },
    xAxis: {
        plotLines: [{
            color: '#4572A7', // 
            width: 2,
            value: 5.5,
            id: 'plotline-1'
        }, {
            color: '#AA4643',
            width: 2,
            value: 8.5,
            id: 'plotline-2'
        }]
    },
    series : [ data.pointsopens, data.pointsclicks ]
};
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6wrJ6/)

**Update1**:
You're returning an array of objects in this function `createPlotlines` and then you put this array inside other array. That's the problem.
Replace your function to the following:

```
function createPlotlines(points, colour) {
    // Create plotlines from point data
    colour = colour || '#CCCCCC';
    var middleYval = 0;
    for (var i in points) {
        middleYval = Math.max(middleYval, points[i].y);
        if (points[i].l) { // l property is true if label should be on for this point
            return {
                color: colour,
                id: 'plotline'+i,
                value: points[i].x,
                width: 1,

            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, i tried it (see my edited OP) but no luck so far.

Comment: tried that too, still no luck.   Thanks for trying, I wonder if maybe something is overwriting the color.

Comment: @Calgacus Can you edit your answer and include `pointsopens` and `pointsclicks` ?

Comment: DOH!!  I messed this one up by using the wrong terminology - I don't even want plotlines - I want the colors for the different series lines to be different.  One line for 'open events per day' the other for 'click events per day'.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

ok, here is what I needed, lineColor:

```
 $data = array(
    "name" => $name,
    "color" => '#00FFFF',
    "lineColor"=> '#00FFFF',
    "data" => $rows
);
```

that code goes in a local function called compileChartData in my php.

Thanks for the effort and sorry for the mixup.

Answer (score 0):

you can change plotLines to target single line.

Or else you can change the whole Yaxis or Xaxis

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            gridLineColor: '#EEEEEE'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Calls'
            },
            gridLineColor: '#EEEEEE'
        }
```